# PHP: Create SQL query for available $_POST variable

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have this $_POST Variable:

```
Array
(
    [phone_1] => 3123213
    [phone_2] => 432423
    [phone_3] => 4234
    [phone_4] => 6456456
    [phone_5] => 7567576
    [phone_6] => 
)
```

Now I have this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table_name SET phone_1 = $_POST['phone1'],
phone_2 = $_POST['phone2'], 
phone_3 = $_POST['phone3'], 
phone_4 = $_POST['phone4'], 
phone_5 = $_POST['phone5'], 
phone_6 = $_POST['phone6'] 
WHERE id=$id
```

What I want to achieve is to dynamically build the SQL query based from the $_POST variable and only include those that have a post value. So the SQL statement should be:

```
UPDATE table_name SET phone_1 = $_POST['phone1'],
    phone_2 = $_POST['phone2'], 
    phone_3 = $_POST['phone3'], 
    phone_4 = $_POST['phone4'], 
    phone_5 = $_POST['phone5']
```

because phone_6 post variable is blank. And yes the $_POST key names is the same as the table field names. TIA!

Comment: you can use foreach statement to loop your $_POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this :

```
<?php
$update = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if(!empty($value)) {
     $update .= $key. "='".$value."',";
   }
}
$update = substr($update,0,-1);
$query = "UPDATE table_name SET ".$update." WHERE id=$id";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postVar    = array_filter($_POST);
$update     = implode(', ', array_map(function($v, $k) { return $k."='".$v."'"; }, $postVar, array_keys($postVar)));
$query      = "UPDATE table_name SET ".$update." WHERE id=$id";
```

it would also be a better approach by avoiding a loop, by using `implode` and `array_map`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Sadly this does not work as per the description, tried it and it still includes $_POST variables that are blank into the SQL statement - would have been a nice approach as it was not using a loop.

Comment: Use array_filter to avoid null values, check my edit..