# Update Table from POST name

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $rName = $row['abb'];
    echo $row['name'];
?>
<html>
    <select id="<?php echo $rName;?>">
        <option value="Yes">Enabled</option>
        <option value="No">Disabled</option>
    </select>
<?php
    echo '<br>';
}
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"/>';
    echo '</form>';
```

So as you can see, Everytime I have a new `$row['name']` its going to create a new selector with the name of `$row['abb']`

How do I do the update the table priv and put the value from that selector into the row with the same name as the selector..

For instance, if I had two `$row['name']` it would create two `$row['abb']`
One would be named op2, the other would be named op3

In my priv table I have rows op2-op24 . So How could I do this so it know to update the correct row with that value?

UPDATE 1**

I tried this

```
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $userIDi = $user['ident'];
            $op2 = $_POST['op2'];
            $op3 = $_POST['op3'];
            $op4 = $_POST['op4'];
            $op5 = $_POST['op5'];
            $op6 = $_POST['op6'];
            $op7 = $_POST['op7'];
            $op8 = $_POST['op8'];
            $op9 = $_POST['op9'];
            $op10 = $_POST['op10'];
            $op11 = $_POST['op11'];
            $op12 = $_POST['op12'];
            $op13 = $_POST['op13'];
$stmt=$con->prepare("UPDATE priv SET op2 = $op2, op3 = $op3, op4 = $op4, op5 = $op5,
 op6 = $op6, op7 = $op7, op8 = $op8, op9 = $op9, op10 = $op10, op11 = $op11, op12 = $op12, op13 = $op13 WHERE ident = :ID");
$stmt->bindparam(":ID", $userIDi);
$stmt->execute();
```

Doing that gave me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' op4 = , op5 = , op6 = , op7 = , op8 = , op9 = , op10 = , op11 = , op12 = , op' at line 1' in /nfs/c11/h05/mnt//html/orderpage.php:204 Stack trace: #0 /nfs/c11/h05/mnt/2080/html/orderpage.php(204): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /nfs/c11/h05//html/orderpage.php on line 204

Comment: give the select a name attribute and assign a variable to a POST/GET array with a form. I don't see the opening form tag, so I don't know which method you're using here.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I understand how to do $new = $_POST['op2'];.... But I might not have all 24 ops so what if I only have too, Do I still have to write all the code out for 24 of them?

Comment: then you'd need to use a `foreach` with a key value and check on empty in the array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you please give me an example with the code I provided.

Comment: *I'm still thinking here*, and TBH, I'm having a bit of trouble now wrapping my head around it. The part that's confusing me is the `<option>`'s you have. I take it you want to use those to update the given row(s) with Yes or No? If those rows are already dynamically created, then as I said, add a name attribute to it etc... then in the update, you'd base yourself on this model: `$var = $_POST['select_name']; ... "UPDATE table SET col_x = 'xxx' WHERE col_y = '$var'"` type of thing. If that's what the question's about.

Comment: ...then `<select id="<?php echo $rName;?>">` would have someting like `<select id="<?php echo $rName;?>" name="select_name">` and/or use the rows value in the `<option>`'s.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please read my Updates.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not if I cant get it to work at all, lol.

Comment: For each variable you are using to perform an update you need to surround it with quotes, i.e `op4 = '$op4'`. Even better would be to use [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did what you said and it worked partially. It only saved op2, It didnt save op3

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35463521/ which is what I had in mind that could help you. Pretty sure you can make use of that one and is dynamic.

Comment: You did it for each variable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I did it for each one.

Comment: If you `print_r($_POST);` what do you get back?

Comment: I got this `Array ( [op2] => Yes [op1] => No [submit] => Submit )`

Comment: Wait, I just realised Why is it using op1? wth

Comment: Have a look at the markup you generated.

Comment: Yep, I just got it working. Now it is saving correctly. Could I ask you one more question. I made another post about it earlier but I CANNOT for life of me get this right. How do I make it so the selector is auto selected on either enabled or disabled based on what the value is from that other priv.

Comment: AS you can see in the above code, I am creatinging the selectors in a while statment for the table access. The values however once submitted get saved into the table priv.. So how do I make this selector "an a while for table access" to be able to read the corresponding value from the table priv

Comment: Everytime I use 2 while statments the other one cancels the other out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you check ou my other post and see if you could help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487194/while-statement-not-echoing-out-info?noredirect=1#comment58670533_35487194